# SQL запрос, вывести, если не совпадает id

Tags: mysql, sql

Такая задача, нужно написать скрипт.

Если id из таблицы `post_district`.`post_id` нет в таблице `post`.`post_id`, то вывести эти id (из этой таблицы `post_district`.`post_id`).

Вот запрос, который я использую:

```sql
SELECT `post_id`
FROM `post_district`
WHERE `post_id`
NOT
IN(SELECT `post_id`
  FROM `post`)
LIMIT 50;
```

Можете посоветовать что-то более продуктивное, таблицы с 2 млн. записями не успевают отработать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT
  pd.`post_id`
FROM
  `post_district` pd
  LEFT JOIN `post` p ON (
    pd.`post_id` = p.`post_id`
  )
WHERE
  p.`post_id` IS NULL
```

Хотя у меня возникают вопросы в необходимости вытягивания из базы 2 миллионов записей

Comment: Вытягивать 2 млн записей не нужно, это я написал  тому, что очень долго выполняются запросы.

Comment: @АлексейСолодуха А почему вы считаете, что этот вариант запроса вытягивает 2 млн записей ? По крайней мере тут нет полного чтения таблицы post, а только подклейка записей из индекса (у вас же есть индекс) )

Comment: @Mike когда-то в древнем Interbase (6?) была бага SELECT в конструкции `IN (SELECT...` выполнялся для каждой записи в родительской таблице. Было больно

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Спасибо, работает шустро

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, можете объяснить почему мой запрос не отрабатывал? на более мелких таблицах,  он выполнялся корректно

Comment: @АлексейСолодуха Могу. Если вы в вопросе приведете план своего запроса (`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`)

Comment: @Mike У него полное чтение таблицы posts

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, значит `NOT IN(SELECT post_id FROM post) LIMIT 50;` не остановится, пока не пройдётся по всей таблице, а `LEFT JOIN` находит первых вхождения? Так?

Comment: @АлексейСолодуха Оба запроса выбирают то, что просили. `SELECT post_id FROM post` выбирает все записи из `post`, А `LEFT JOIN post p ON (
    pd.post_id = p.post_id
  )` только те, для которых выполняется условие `pd.post_id = p.post_id`